# Juypter Notebooks Presentation Notes Server Error 500 403

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, reveal.js

I've created a Jupyter Notebook and I'm preparing it for presentation mode. I'm executing the following command to convert my notebook to slides and serve it on a local webserver:

`jupyter-nbconvert My_Notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve`

When attempting to enter "Presentation Mode", by pressing `s` I encounter the following in the new window:

> 404: Not Found

The terminal reports

> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.html (127.0.0.1) 1.58ms

Answer (score 2):

How I solved this by cloning reveal.js to my local machine, instead of relying on the CDN that is contacted.

Specifically, run: `git clone https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js.git` in the directory your starting your slideshow from.

I then use: `jupyter-nbconvert My_Notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve --reveal-prefix reveal.js`

to execute the slide show, note the explicit path to the reveal library

Comment: This solution is confirmed by the [nbconvert docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html) for `SlidesExporter.reveal_url_prefix`: "The URL prefix for reveal.js. This can be a a relative URL for a local copy of reveal.js, or point to a CDN. **For speaker notes to work, a local reveal.js prefix must be used.**"